# Hub bearing grease: regular or for cv joint?

Tags: bearing, grease, cv-joint

The car I'm rebuilding uses this kind of bearing in the transmission axles hubs. Which grease should they use? Regular or the one for C.V. joints?

[image]

Comment: What is the year/make/model of the vehicle you are rebuilding? What type of transmission?

Comment: Skoda Estelle '82, RWD, rear mounted engine, transmission by axles in half housing, in swinging arm suspension. Only those bearings next to the hub, which should accept some axle tilting degree.

Answer (score 2):

If the bearing didn't come with grease, or a recommendation for grease, I'd be inclined to use high temperature wheel bearing grease.

Comment: The green one for CV joints would suffice?

Comment: They're built to a different recipe, because the loading is different. I'd spend the minimal amount and get the correct stuff. I can't say if it would work or not, of course, but I just wouldn't trust it; bearings cost money, and usually a lot of swearing to get them into place.